# Outlook Web Addin - How to modify outlook ribbon dynamically on control button clicked

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

How can I modify my outlook ribbon containing controls that I have defined in my manifest? I would like to dynamically modify control labels and potentially icons being used when a control button is clicked. For example, on button click I will execute a command that will then change my control label/icon. General idea is to indicate that add-in is enabled/disabled. Is this possible yet in web based outlook add-ins developed in javascript/angular compared to vsto/com?

Comment: Currently the feature of modifying the ribbon label/icon, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for the help, have submitted the idea at this url for consideration. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/41946427-outlook-add-in-ribbon-customization